# Play-pac4j Twitter auth expiring and throwing exceptions

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth, playframework-2.3

I'm seeing this a number of TwitterClient sessions become expired and it results in an exception. From the best I can tell the twitter oAuth session isn't suppose to expire so I'm wondering what might be causing this issue? I am using memcache to store user sessions because our site scales across many instances which might factor into the matter but I was seeing this behavior before moving to memcache so I believe this might be from something else.

Ideally I am looking for ideas on what might be causing this so I can fix it but in the short term I would be grateful if anyone could tell me how to intercept this exception and handle it so my users aren't seeing an error screen.

I am using play 2.3.3 and play-pac4j 1.6

```
 ERROR o.p.oauth.client.BaseOAuth10Client: Token request expired
  ERROR play: Cannot invoke the action, eventually got an error: org.pac4j.oauth.client.exception.OAuthCredentialsException: Token request expired
  ERROR application: 
  ! @6lhge4dme - Internal server error, for (GET) [/league/callback?client_name=TwitterClient&oauth_token=tgk8pilQpkwlgt5kU01ieK1lgMO33Vv0&oauth_verifier=DhE9aFaVxsbSWmm7SN34IrNHR3gcixbe] ->
  play.api.Application$$anon$1: Execution exception[[OAuthCredentialsException: Token request expired]]
    at play.api.Application$class.handleError(Application.scala:296) ~[com.typesafe.play.play_2.10-2.3.5.jar:2.3.5]
    at play.core.server.servlet.DefaultWarApplication.handleError(Play2Server.scala:118) [com.github.play2war.play2-war-core-common_2.10-1.3-beta2.jar:1.3-beta2]
    at play.core.server.servlet.Play2GenericServletRequestHandler$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$7.apply(RequestHandler.scala:376) [com.github.play2war.play2-war-core-common_2.10-1.3-beta2.jar:1.3-beta2]
    at play.core.server.servlet.Play2GenericServletRequestHandler$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$7.apply(RequestHandler.scala:376) [com.github.play2war.play2-war-core-commo...
 ...n_2.10-1.3-beta2.jar:  1.3-beta2]
 ...n_2.10-1.3-beta2.jar:   at scala.Option.fold(Option.scala:157) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.10.4.jar:na]
 ...n_2.10-1.3-beta2.jar:   at play.core.server.servlet.Play2GenericServletRequestHandler$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(RequestHandler.scala:375) [com.github.play2war.play2-war-core-common_2.10-1.3-beta2.jar:1.3-beta2]
 ...n_2.10-1.3-beta2.jar:   at play.core.server.servlet.Play2GenericServletRequestHandler$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(RequestHandler.scala:372) [com.github.play2war.play2-war-core-common_2.10-1.3-beta2.jar:1.3-beta2]
 ...n_2.10-1.3-beta2.jar:   at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$recoverWith$1.apply(Future.scala:344) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.10.4.jar:na]
 ...n_2.10-1.3-beta2.jar:   at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$recoverWith$1.apply(Future.scala:343) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.10.4.jar:na]
 ...n_2.10-1.3-beta2.jar:   at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.10.4.jar:na]
 ...n_2.10-1.3-beta2.jar:   at play.api.libs.iteratee.Execution$trampoline$.execute(Execution.scala:46) [com.typesafe.play.play-iteratees_2.10-2.3.5.jar:2.3.5...
 ...:  ]
 ...:   at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.executeWithValue(Promise.scala:40) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.10.4.jar:na]
 ...:   at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryComplete(Promise.scala:248) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.10.4.jar:na]
 ...:   at scala.concurrent.Promise$class.complete(Promise.scala:55) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.10.4.jar:na]
 ...:   at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.complete(Promise.scala:153) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.10.4.jar:na]
 ...:   at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:23) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.10.4.jar:na]
 ...:   at play.core.j.HttpExecutionContext$$anon$2.run(HttpExecutionContext.scala:40) [com.typesafe.play.play_2.10-2.3.5.jar:2.3.5]
 ...:   at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:41) [com.typesafe.akka.akka-actor_2.10-2.3.4.jar:na]
 ...:   at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:393) [com.typesafe.akka.akka-...
 ...actor_2.10-2.3.4.jar:  na]
 ...actor_2.10-2.3.4.jar:   at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.10.4.jar:na]
 ...actor_2.10-2.3.4.jar:   at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.10.4.jar:na]
 ...actor_2.10-2.3.4.jar:   at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.10.4.jar:na]
 ...actor_2.10-2.3.4.jar:   at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.10.4.jar:na]
 ...actor_2.10-2.3.4.jar:  Caused by: org.pac4j.oauth.client.exception.OAuthCredentialsException: Token request expired
 ...actor_2.10-2.3.4.jar:   at org.pac4j.oauth.client.BaseOAuth10Client.getAccessToken(BaseOAuth10Client.java:100) ~[org.pac4j.pac4j-oauth-1.6.0.jar:na]
 ...actor_2.10-2.3.4.jar:   at org.pac4j.oauth.client.BaseOAuthClient.retrieveUserProfile(BaseOAuthClient.java:166) ~[org.pac4j.pac4j-oauth-1.6.0.jar:na]
 ...actor_2.10-2.3.4.jar:   at org.pac4j.oauth.client.BaseOAuthClient.retrieveUserProfile(BaseOAuthClient.java:45) ~[org.pa...
 ...c4j.pac4j-oauth-1.6.0.jar:  na]
 ...c4j.pac4j-oauth-1.6.0.jar:      at org.pac4j.core.client.BaseClient.getUserProfile(BaseClient.java:231) ~[org.pac4j.pac4j-core-1.6.0.jar:na]
 ...c4j.pac4j-oauth-1.6.0.jar:      at org.pac4j.play.CallbackController$1.apply(CallbackController.java:95) ~[org.pac4j.play-pac4j_java-1.3.0.jar:na]
 ...c4j.pac4j-oauth-1.6.0.jar:      at org.pac4j.play.CallbackController$1.apply(CallbackController.java:69) ~[org.pac4j.play-pac4j_java-1.3.0.jar:na]
 ...c4j.pac4j-oauth-1.6.0.jar:      at play.core.j.FPromiseHelper$$anonfun$promise$2.apply(FPromiseHelper.scala:36) ~[com.typesafe.play.play_2.10-2.3.5.jar:2.3.5]
 ...c4j.pac4j-oauth-1.6.0.jar:      at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.10.4.jar:na]
 ...c4j.pac4j-oauth-1.6.0.jar:      at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.10.4.jar:na]
 ...c4j.pac4j-oauth-1.6.0.jar:      ... 7 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer to one of my questions, how to intercept the Exceptions but I'm still not too sure what causes this as I haven't been able to reproduce it though it shows up in my logs more often then I would like.

Intercepting the exceptions is as simple as overriding the onError() method in your Global.java and handle the exception

```
@Override
    public Promise<Result> onError(RequestHeader req, Throwable t) {
        //Check for session timeout for Twitter Clients and log them out if something is wrong.
        if(t instanceof OAuthCredentialsException){
            Logger.warn("[LiveError] OAuthException: Loguser out.",t);

            //Attempt to log user out and go to logging page
            return Promise.<Result>pure(org.pac4j.play.CallbackController.logoutAndRedirect());
        }

        Logger.warn("[LiveError] Encountered an unexpected error,",t);
        return Promise.<Result>pure(internalServerError(views.html.league.error.render("Sorry, we have an error!  "+t.getMessage())));
    }
```

Here's the reference where I got the answer:  https://groups.google.com/d/msg/pac4j-users/cy9sZw3KJnQ/L0T7nv0M7QEJ